# java process builder redirect.appendTo(log)

Tags: java, processbuilder

Is it possible to replace the content of an output file with the redirect option withing the java process builder?

code:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb2 =
           new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /home/james/YCSB/bin/simulations/"+CommandGenerator.Simulation_id+".dat | sort -n");                                                                                                                                                                 
           File log2 = new File("/home/james/YCSB/bin/simulations/"+CommandGenerator.Simulation_id+".dat");
           pb2.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log2));
           pb2.redirectErrorStream(true);
           assert pb2.redirectOutput().file() == log2;

           Process p2 = pb2.start();
```

I wish to replace the content of `log2` with the output of the command. I am unsure if this is possible however, as the process builder working directory is also the same as the output file `log2`.

In sort, my process builder needs to read a file, sorts the content and then writes it back, replacing the un-sorted content. At the moment it sorts the content but then when writing it back to the `log2` file it just puts the output at the bottom of the file, effectively doubling `log2`'s content rather than overwriting it.

Comment: Don't `appendTo`, just use [`to`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.Redirect.html#to(java.io.File)). The issue will be that you will overwrite the file _as_ you are reading it - you'll have an issue. It's usual to write to a `tmp` file and then replace the original file _after_ you've successfully read the input file.

Comment: I tried using just 'to' before I wrote the question but I wasn't getting any output at all. I took your advice however and wrote to a temp file using 'to' before writing back, all is working now. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you sort it this way? You could just read it, do the sort with Collections.sort() in Java and write back? This is a very complicated solution for a very simple problem, and, thereby, an antipattern.